How to disable announcements for workout start in iOS 18 public beta?
I’m using the iOS 18 public beta and the watchOS 11 public beta.
Since upgrading, I use the automatic workout detection and I get the “announcements” when my watch detects I’m cycling - asking if I want to start a cycling workout.

I want the workout detection.
I don’t want to hear the announcement in paired headphones.

I’ve disabled voice feedback in the workout settings in the watch app. I’ve tried to disable announces for fitness via the iOS settings.
Can I have the workouts be detected and not hear it announced?

Workout app is the one you need to disable Siri announcements, no?

@bmike - there’s no option for workout app in settings -> notifications -> announce.

Then your device has corrupt database or Apple shipped a bug and you fell into it…

Beta = buggy. There should be a built-in app, Feedback Assistant in Beta installations.

If anyone wonders, this is on topic since we rescinded the beta prohibition with this edit on meta in August 2014

yeah, i was worried this was due to the beta. i’ve filled out a thing in feedback assistant. thanks for your help @bmike!

My hunch is Apple considers these workout reminders as time sensitive. Have you reviewed your announcement settings? You could should be able to turn all of them off or just for that app.

Siri automatically enables app notifications for apps that use time-sensitive notifications, but you can change the settings at any time.


Go to Settings  > Siri & Search > Announce Notifications, then turn on Announce Notifications.

In your case, if you want Siri to not announce notifications from the workout app, then turn off Announce Notifications for that app.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/have-siri-announce-calls-and-notifications-iph838fd6fd4/ios


If the above setting doesn’t work, you’ll have to choose to disable detection (which you don’t want either)

To turn this setting on or off, open the Settings app on your Apple Watch, tap Workout, then go to Start Workout Reminder or End Workout Reminder.

From the Workout app manual.

Since the workout app can be deleted from the watch, if you can’t find it in settings you might try deleting it. Think if you want to keep the data it generated in health app or not and then try reinstalling that app and repeat the configuration steps above.
Last resort would be to erase the device and test with no restore and then decide to try and restore (after another erase) or work with Apple support to understand why your device isn’t working like others.

this doesn’t solve my problem. i want it to remind me. i dont want it to announce it via headphones.

Ok @naydichev that wasn’t at all clear to me - see my edits. You should have control over this too.
